# Fill gaps in Pandas multi index with start and end timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

From a DataFrame like the following:

```
                                                   value    fill
start                     end
2016-07-15 00:46:11       2016-07-19 03:35:34      1        a
2016-08-21 07:55:31       2016-08-22 18:24:49      2        b
2016-09-26 03:09:12       2016-09-26 06:06:12      3        c
```

I'm looking for a way to add rows filling the gaps, each new row taking the `fill` column of the existing previous adjacent row as its new `value`.

The output of the previous example would then be:

```
                                                   value 
start                     end
2016-07-15 00:46:11       2016-07-19 03:35:34      1
2016-07-19 03:35:34       2016-08-21 07:55:31      a
2016-08-21 07:55:31       2016-08-22 18:24:49      2
2016-08-22 18:24:49       2016-09-26 03:09:12      b
2016-09-26 03:09:12       2016-09-26 06:06:12      3
```

A vectorized method, avoiding looping over the DataFrame in pure Python, would be heavily preferred as I have to deal with massive amounts of rows.

Comment: did you try `df.stack()`?

Answer (score 2):

use [DataFrame.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method:

```
In [189]: df.stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).to_frame('value')
Out[189]:
                                        value
start               end
2016-07-15 00:46:11 2016-07-19 03:35:34     1
                    2016-07-19 03:35:34     a
2016-08-21 07:55:31 2016-08-22 18:24:49     2
                    2016-08-22 18:24:49     b
2016-09-26 03:09:12 2016-09-26 06:06:12     3
                    2016-09-26 06:06:12     c
```

Comment: I think it is no what OP have as desired output. But maybe i am wrong.